# dapper , how to read oracle retruing id

Tags: oracle, return, dapper

i want get the return id after a insert .
the field is RAW(16) in oracle ,and Guid in C#

```
    public class Test
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid? PlanId { get; set; }

        public bool State { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

i have created a RawGuidHandler,inherited from SqlMapper.TypeHandler

```
    internal class RawGuidHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Guid>
    {
        public override Guid Parse(object value)
        {
            if (value is byte[] byteArray)
            {
                return new Guid(byteArray);
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException("RawGuidHandler->Parse");
        }

        public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, Guid value)
        {
            if (value != Guid.Empty)
            {
                parameter.Value = value.ToByteArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

the execute code bellow:

```
            var conn = new OracleConnection(connBuilder.ToString());

            var t = new Test
            {
                PlanId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                State = true
            };

            var sql = "INSERT INTO \"tb_Test\" ( \"PlanId\", \"State\") VALUES ( :PlanId, :State) returning \"Id\" into :Id";

            var param = new DynamicParameters();
            param.Add(":PlanId", t.PlanId);
            param.Add(":State", t.State);

            param.Add(":Id", dbType: DbType.Binary, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size:16);

                conn.Execute(sql, param: param);
                var id = param.Get<Guid>("Id");
```

the sql executed successfully.  but , when read id from param ,

```
 var id = param.Get<Guid>("Id");
```

i got an error
**Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Dapper.dll**
the param.Get<> did not call RawGuidHandler , it just does a

```
return (T)val;
```

how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

i did some modify from the source code , then it worked.

```
        public T Get<T>(string name)
        {
            var paramInfo = parameters[Clean(name)];
            var attachedParam = paramInfo.AttachedParam;
            object val = attachedParam == null ? paramInfo.Value : attachedParam.Value;
            if (val == DBNull.Value)
            {
                if (default(T) != null)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Attempting to cast a DBNull to a non nullable type! Note that out/return parameters will not have updated values until the data stream completes (after the 'foreach' for Query(..., buffered: false), or after the GridReader has been disposed for QueryMultiple)");
                }
                return default;
            }
#pragma warning disable 618
            SqlMapper.LookupDbType(typeof(T), name, true, out var handler);
#pragma warning disable 618

            if (handler != null)
            {
                return (T)handler.Parse(typeof(T), val);
            }

            return (T)val;
        }
```